# AWS Auth.currentCredentials() failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, authentication, expo

My expo (react native) project has been working completely fine. All i did was try build it on an android device and now suddenly its failing on both android and ios.  Even if i go back versions on git it still errors on the same place (where before this used to work perfectly).

It errors on this line

```
export const getIdentityId = async () => {
  try {
    const credentials = await Auth.currentCredentials()
    /* eslint-disable-next-line */
    const identityId = credentials._identityId
    return { identityId }
  } catch (error) {
    return { error }
  }
}
```

error looks like this

```
[TypeError: n.getPromise is not a function. (In 'n.getPromise()', 'n.getPromise' is undefined)]
```

As i said there is zero code change that caused this issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay after lots of struggling i deleted my project and recloned it (with an npm install) and it works again.  No idea...

Answer (score 0):

Having come across this answer while resolving an issue in my own app, a clarification might help someone else:

OP's problem was probably with the configuration between his app's client and the AWS ID pool

Note in the docs, AWS Credentials hit the ID pool:

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#aws-auth

The resolution to his problem probably (as it was with mine) was some kind of change to the role settings in the Identity Pool which needed to be fixed.

In my case, I was confused because my Signin/Login/etc was all working just fine.  Then, I had that "oh duh" moment when I looked and remembered that those, while related, are configured separately.

Chances are that, because his resolution was to reclone a new app and it worked like magic, that the error was made manually in the AWS Console and his underlying settings (yaml file, etc) was correct...

If you are using the AWS-cli, at least part of the results of this Auth.currentCredentials() call is your AWS ClI configuration, so you don't already know this:

```
cat ~/.aws/credentials
```

is a handy bash command to keep in mind...

Good hunting.

Comment: thanks for your reply unfortuanately this was so long ago that i cant remember much about it and cant say whether your fix was indeed my issue but hopefully this helps someone else.